# Remove/disable/override Swing's focus traversal keys

Tags: java, swing, focus, keylistener

Note: see the edit (save some time reading)

I'm trying to make my mind-mapping program respond to shortcuts like CTRL+RIGHT (reordering nodes) and TAB (insert child at next indent level).  I have a `JPanel` that handles all of the keystrokes.  It resides inside of a `JTabbedPane` that might be the cause for Key Bindings not working.  I've chickened out and decided to just use `KeyListener`.

The problem is that with the aforementioned key combinations, Swing automatically shifts the focus to some other component.  I'd rather not manually put `setFocusable(false)` everywhere.  How can I disable these shortcuts altogether in such a way that the focus will not be shifted, and the relevant `KeyEvent`s will still be sent to my `JPanel`?

**Edit**:
I used the following code:

```
for (int id : new int[] {KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, KeyboardFocusManager.UP_CYCLE_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, KeyboardFocusManager.DOWN_CYCLE_TRAVERSAL_KEYS})
    setFocusTraversalKeys(id, Collections.EMPTY_SET);
```

to disable the default traversal keys (particularly `TAB`.)

Now the issue is actually why CTRL+UP causes a loss of focus.  When pressing CTRL+DOWN, for instance, it's fine.  The component behaves as expected.  But with CTRL+UP, it works as expected and then focus is shifted/lost somehow.  Can anyone say what CTRL+UP means and how to disable it wherever it is?  Google isn't helping.

Answer (score 2):

- [KeyBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) are used for all `KeyEvents` implemented in Swing APIs, maybe there is/are conflict
- is required to override required `KeyBindings`, change used Keys, set to null, e.i. depends of your requirements
- list of [`KeyBindings` by @camickr](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  (See my edit)
Will camickr's list help me determine why CTRL+UP is behaving so differently?

Comment: +1, @Tangmeister, you need to know what components you are displaying. Usually a component will bind CTRL+UP/DOWN together so it is strange that one works and the other doesn't. I did notice that a JTabbedPane binds these key stroke differently.